# How to grow a ListView when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and a very large amount of Items that go into it (like high hundreds). I would like to be able to start the ListView off with something like 20 items and grow it as the user scrolls so it's not as "overwhelming"

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Remember thats all objects you are gonna store on someones phone on ram.  Just paginate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

I made an observable scroll view class.

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView{
    private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
        this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
        super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);
        if(scrollViewListener != null) {
            scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, x, y, oldx, oldy);
        }
    }
```

}

I created a new interface called Scroll View Listener.

```
public interface ScrollViewListener {
void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy);
```

}

Then in the activity I implemented this interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ScrollViewListener {
```

Then it will force you to use the following method.

```
// scroll view listener. used to load new page if user scrolls to bottom
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
        int oldx, int oldy) {
    View view = (View) scrollView
            .getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView
            .getScrollY()));

    if (diff <= DISTANCE_FROM_BOTTOM) {
        LOADNEXTTHINGS();
    }

}
```

The `DISTANCE_FROM_BOTTOM` is in pixels if I remember correctly.

Keep in mind that `LOADNEXTTHINGS()` will be called if the user is changing the scroll position and in the range that is between `diff <= DISTANCE_FROM_BOTTOM`.  You should have a loading value to control this... like

```
if(diff <= DISTANCE_FROM_BOTTOM && !loadingNextThings){
    loadingNextThings = true;
    LOADNEXTTHINGS();
}
```

then when you are done loading next things do `loadingNextThings = false;`

Personally, I prefer using FSMs.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement pull to refresh . check [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) with complete source code

Answer (score 0):

You can use Endless adapter, it is simply notify you when you reach the bottm of your list view so you can add more data to the adapter. like adding 20 elements every time you reach the bottom.

here is the link:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless